# Is there a Textmate bundle to replace umlauts?

Tags: textmate, bundle, replace

I often find myself going through text files replacing German umlauts, for example:

- ä -> ae
- ü -> ue
- ö -> oe
- ß -> sz
- the same applies for their capitalized variants

Going through find/replace for this is tedious, so I wonder if there's a bundle for this or if someone could come up with a small code snippet?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but why are you replacing them? I am not saying you should not, but I am curious as to the root cause (OCD of mine)

Comment: I'm using a phplist for sending newsletters and for some reason, it won't transmit umlauts correctly. They will appear as something completely different.

Comment: Then you've probably got a character encoding problem that you might be able to fix, rather than replacing the awkward characters. For example, are the files in UTF-8? If not, can Textmate convert them? That might just fix it.

Comment: The thing is, I'm just copy-pasting the text into phplist's form for plaintext messages, and it will be delivered broken. I haven't been able to trace the problem yet, if I can get more details, I'll probably open a question here anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know of any bundle that does that specific task, remember that TextMate has the ability to execute any scripting language that recognizes the shebang (#!) sequence as a language indicator, so if you're familiar with PHP, Perl, bash, Ruby or anything else that can use it, you can simply write a command, perhaps adding it to the existing Text bundle. Alternatively, you could record a macro (Bundles>Macros>Start Recording) of the steps you take to accomplish the find/replace.

Comment: I am very familiar with all of them, but I can't really see how I would access the contents of my document in, let's say Ruby, and then replace all those characters. TextMate doesn't seem to have a straightforward tutorial on this.

Comment: TextMate offers environment variables that can be accessed by the scripts in a bundle. I don't see one for the contents of a document (which seems odd, yes), but there is one for the selected contents, TM_SELECTED_TEXT. Check out http://manual.macromates.com/en/environment_variables.html. But the easiest method would probably be to record a macro.

Comment: Oh that's nice, I'll go ahead and see if I can get into programming, if not, a macro is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing an HTML or PHP file you just need to hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>&</kbd> to replace all "special characters" in your selection with their HTML Entities counterpart.

If it's not an HTML document you can still use the cog menu at the bottom of the window and navigate to HTML -> Entities -> Convert Selection to Entities.

Edit:

You can do this by recording and saving a macro. Here is how I'd do it:

1. Start recording your macro

Bundle -> Macros -> Start Recording

1. Do consecutive searches & replaces for all the special characters you want to convert.
2. Stop recording.
3. Save the macro and give it a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I know this command, I use it all the time :) But I don't want HTML entities like `&auml;`, I want the specific (and easy-to read) replacement `ae`.